# How to access index.php page when index.html has priority

Tags: indexing, url-routing

I have a wordpress site that is using an **index.php** page.

Now the website is not live yet, so I added an **index.html** page for a temp page - So that users will not see the index.php page, yet.

But now i cannot access my index.php file when visiting: http://mysite.com/index.php - It redirects me straight to http://mysite.com, which serves the index.html page

How can I view my index.php page?

NOTE: my htaccess file has the following:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

If I remove this, the default page people see is the index.php, which I don't want them to see. Only I want to be able to view the index.php file

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I am in the same situation as you and I couldn't find any way to see the index.php file that is on the server.

I would recommend you to create another directory with wordpress installed on while you developp your website. Once you have done everything you need (create pages, create your custom theme, etc) simply export your content using the export function built in wordpress and import it on your public wordpress. Same thing goes with plugins and theme, you just have to do it manually since there are no export function for those.

If you don't have enough space on your server, you can do it on your own computer by using [EasyPhp](http://www.easyphp.org/). It basically install every server component on your computer so it can be accessed from your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Direct users to index.php and at the head of the document check either for your specific IP address or alternately for a cookie that allows you to view the index.php page, and redirect everyone else to back to index.html. When you are ready to launch the page, just remove this function and everyone else will then be able to view the index.php file as well.